# How to test nested connected components using Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test nested connected components (Redux connected):
The Main component has Container component and are provided by store wrapper in App.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Main from './components/Main';
import './App.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import createStore from './redux'
import applyConfigSettings from './config'

// Apply config overrides
applyConfigSettings()

const store = createStore()

class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <Main/>
      </Provider>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.svg';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import Container from './Container'

export class Main extends Component {

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Pomodoro App</h1>
                </header>
                <Container/>
            </div>
        );
    } 
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      fetching: state.user.fetching,
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {

    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)
```

Container.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


export class Container extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="grid-root">

            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      fetching: state.user.fetching,
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {

    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container)
```

All this is created using Create-react-app library. I have installed Enzyme too for testing. Here is my test file for Main.test.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

import {Main} from '../../components/Main'
import ContainerConnect, {Container} from '../../components/Container';

import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';

describe('Main', () => {
    let wrapper;
    let mountWrapper;
    it('wraps all the contents in a div with .App class', () => {
        wrapper = shallow(<Main />);
        expect(wrapper.find('.App').length).toEqual(1);
    });

    it('wraps content of header in a div with .App-header class', () => {
        wrapper = shallow(<Main />);
        expect(wrapper.find('.App-header').length).toEqual(1);
    });

    it('mount', () => {
        const middlewares = [];
        const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
        const initialState = {}
        const store = mockStore(initialState)
        mountWrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                    <Main />
            </Provider>
        );
    });

  })
```

I get following error for the last test:

```
 FAIL  src/tests/components/Main.test.js
  ● Console

    console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9643
      The above error occurred in the <Connect(Container)> component:
          in Connect(Container) (at Main.js:16)
          in div (at Main.js:11)
          in Main (at Main.test.js:31)
          in Provider (created by WrapperComponent)
          in WrapperComponent

      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit some link to fb to learn more about error boundaries.

  ● Main › mount

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetching' of undefined

      at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (src/components/Container.js:18:30)
      at mapToPropsProxy (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps.js:54:92)
      at Function.detectFactoryAndVerify (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps.js:63:19)
      at mapToPropsProxy (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps.js:54:46)
      at handleFirstCall (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/selectorFactory.js:37:18)
      at pureFinalPropsSelector (node_modules/react-redux/lib/connect/selectorFactory.js:85:81)
      at Object.runComponentSelector [as run] (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:43:25)
      at Connect.initSelector (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:195:23)
      at new Connect (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:136:15)
      at constructClassInstance (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6801:20)
      at updateClassComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8336:9)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8982:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11814:16)
      at workLoop (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11843:26)
      at renderRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11874:9)
      at performWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12449:24)
      at performWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12370:9)
      at performSyncWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12347:5)
      at requestWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12247:7)
      at scheduleWorkImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12122:13)
      at scheduleWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12082:12)
      at scheduleRootUpdate (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12710:5)
      at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12738:12)
      at Object.updateContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12765:14)
      at ReactRoot.Object.<anonymous>.ReactRoot.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16069:15)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16488:14
      at Object.unbatchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12557:12)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16484:17)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16543:12)
      at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:218:50)
      at new ReactWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:98:16)
      at mount (node_modules/enzyme/build/mount.js:19:10)
      at Object.it (src/tests/components/Main.test.js:29:42)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
```

Is it so hard to test nested connected components? I have to go and use more of it going forward in the application as well. And also does this mean that testing button clicks and all is harder to test as well?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are trying to test, you should not have to deal with redux at all.

Since you are testing your `<Main />` component and whether it renders the header properly, just mock your `<Container />` completely:

```
jest.mock('../../components/Container', () => ()=> <div id="mockContainer">
   mockContainer
</div>);
```

Then you can shallow mount your `<Main />` without worrying about redux.

After that, when you start unit testing your `<Container />`, just unit test the React.Component class and do not bother with the connected Component, testing it is redundant.

In other words, you should be able to test any React app without ever having to mock the redux store. Just mock connected components entirely.

[More info here](https://hackernoon.com/how-do-you-mock-a-react-component-with-jest-unit-test-javascript-tutorial-example-spy-jest-enzyme-6c681f812a00)

Comment: I am lost mate :( but will give it a try.

Comment: But your solution is different, what if I want to test the connected component ?

Comment: The purpose of unit test is to only test one component at a time while isolating yourself from the other dependencies. So in other words just test one component at a time while mocking everything else. If you want to test the whole thing, I suggest you look into ent to end testing

Comment: but still, I get the error even if I do it independently, please check the errors I posted.